# Mod rewrite multiple languages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Alright im doing a site which is available in multiple languages. I have ran into some problems with my mod rewrite. I'm trying to do this:

Normal page without extra querystrings: `/en/whatever`

And the page with problems (with querystrings): `/en/dashboard/project/projectid`

And my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ $1?lang=en [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/project/([a-z0-9]+)$ projectdashboard.php?id=$1
```

But the `?lang=en` is getting lost when opening this page: `/en/dashboard/project/projectid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *QSA* flag in both rules:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ $1?lang=en [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/project/([a-z0-9]+)$ projectdashboard.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```